# Search WP, small plugin

Tags: search, plugins, wordpress

I need function in WP which getting search query and redirect on link like  {site.com}/search/{search_query}

When i typed search query on english and press to search button and i was redirected on page search {host.com}/search/{search_query} 
When I did it again but only on others languages it was redirected me on page {host.com}/search/ and show me 404 page. 
But when a typed in URL {host.com}/search/{search_query_another_lanuage} it work
How can i get data from search input

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What did you try actually ? You can achieve this using .htaccess

Comment: Problem in: when i typing on english then go to search {site.com}/search/{search_query} but when i typing on other languages then go to {site.com}/search and show me 404 page. but if I set url {site.com}/search/{search_query_another_language} its OK. 
I need to get query and set it for {site.com}/search/{search_query}

Comment: Please be more specific (update your question instead of add comment), I don't understand your problem...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all addressing to Site Architecture where you can find How to modify Search, check this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Architecture_1.5#Search_Form

Second, if you're looking for Search Plugin which supports search with multilingual then here is one... http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/

Also you can opt for other two high rated Search Plugin available on WordPress...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpsearch/
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/

Comment: Which one you tried and it's not working?

Please be specific, so we can put relevant comments to WordPress Plugin support.

Also you can ask for support in WP support forum under that plugins.

And you can ask to Plugin Developer directly.

Comment: Maybe WP doesn't see search query if typing on other languages? Not transfer. If establish url in browser {host.com}/search/{search_query_another_lanuage} its work good

Comment: What hook for click search button? Maybe i need plugin, when press search button or submit searchform , and get data from input and redirect to {host.com}/search/{search}

Comment: if you're using Relevanssi then below are the links for support...

1. http://wordpress.org/tags/relevanssi?forum_id=10
2. http://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/query_posts/
3. http://www.relevanssi.com/category/knowledge-base/

Comment: I also got one good ref. check this out...

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-relevanssi-a-better-search-making-relevanssi-better-at-multilanguage

Comment: Good to know, finally you found some solution

Comment: But where, why data not transferred if they on not english(

Comment: For Multilingual what Plugin you're using?

Comment: qTranslate, but it's not fault plugin, i deactivate his.

Comment: You must tried out using wpml.org, it's more fine tune with WordPress and has more support community available online.